# Web hooks on Ngrok?

Tags: java, python, macos, terminal, webhooks

I am using Mac OS, Terminal

I am trying to build a Kik Bot and require a web hook. I've looked at the documentation. I've downloaded ngrok and ran it once. Now I need to `install auth token`. It in the form:

```
./ngrok authtoken ....[TOKEN NUM]
```

How do I exactly install this? I ran this in terminal, but it says no path found etc... Help?

Answer (score 0):

sign up https://ngrok.com/signup and get authtoken from https://dashboard.ngrok.com